# How to generate matplotlib plot and keep their sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a large number of diagrams (all of the same size) which I want to display in a single file.

So I used something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(100)
for i in range (0,99):
    ax[i] = draw_my_diagram(i)
```

The problem that I have, is that the plotted diagrams get really small if i do it in this way. But I want to keep their original size.
I tried to set their figsize manually to the value what I thought I needed them to be, but this messed up the plot. In particular, I drew some patches in the plot, which were not in the desired position and shape anymore.

So what would be the best way to solve this? Maybe there is even a flag that I can set to just keep the original size of the subplots?

Comment: There is no flag. And I strongly doubt you will be able to create a single file of the size of 100 times the original one.. that would simply be too huge, but the general principle would indeed be to multiply the orignal figure size by the number of subplots. Due to different margins, the sizes would be slightly off though. Is this what you're asking about? Also note that your code does not make much sense; `draw_my_diagram` would need to take an argument telling in which of the 100 axes to plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Do you mean too huge in the sense of length and width or in the sense of file size? Nevertheless, in either case i have to disagree, because I already created such a picture. It just does not look as expected.  Maybe, the subplots methode is just not suited for what I need. I will try to just create on ax, in which i plot everything (at the right position)

Comment: Yes, huge in the true sense of the word. I don't know what you're aiming at, but consider e.g. pdf export. If the default size of the figure is 6 inch, you would create a 600 inch (=240 meter) long pdf, which noone can reasonable view or print. Instead one would rather put maybe 2 figures per page.